# Does the JVM make two separate instances of classes that are implemented in different applications?

Tags: java, jar, jvm

Imagine two simple java applications. 
Both of them are implementing the same JAR file containting an enum file like this:

```
enum enum1{
   value1;
}
```

In both the applications I print the enum1.value1´s hashcode.

```
System.out.print(enum1.value1.hashCode());
```

How does the JVM work since the hashcodes are not equal even if the JAR file that the two applications implement is the same?

Why are not the hashcodes equal since it is the same JAR file the both applications implement?

**EDIT**
I have two applications that access a database. They are run within the same JVM. I would like to implement a locking mechanism so that when application 1 is writing to the database, application 2 has to wait for its turn (that is when the lock has been released by application 1). My solution is, if possible, to make an interface that has some ReentrantLocks declared or an enum that should act as lock and is used by the two applications. But then the instance of the interface/enum should be equal in both the applications, because you can only synchronize the same object.

**EDIT 2**
This is the architecture:

```
App1.jar              Commons.jar         App2.jar
App1Main.class        Commons.class       App2Main.class
```

Both App1 and App2 includes Commons.jar. The commons.class is just a simple singleton class.
In both App1 and App2 I print the commons instance hashcode:

```
System.out.println(Commons.getInstance().hashCode());
```

Both java applications are run like "java -jar app1" and "java -jar app2" so there are two processes when they are running.

But they print different hashcodes and that is, what I belive (correct me if I am wrong), because they have been loaded by different class loaders. But the mystic arrives when I print the classloader in both apps:

```
System.out.print(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().hashCode());
```

Then the hashcode is equal in both applications.

Comment: Do you _need_ them to be equal?

Comment: Yes, look at my edit for explaination.

Comment: I believe your intended solution will be brittle.  Consider instead having a common pool of database connections and for two applications have only one entry.  Then application 2 cannot access the database until application 1 is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear whether you're talking about two applications within the same process or not. Even if you are, if those two applications have separate `ClassLoader` instances loading the same jar file, the two enum types are *different types* as far as the JVM is concerned. If you want a *single* type within a process used by two applications, it has to be loaded by a single classloader.

Comment: How can I make the applications be loaded by the same classloader?

Comment: Interesting, as always :) What do you mean by "the two enum types are *different types*"?

Comment: @Raffaele: The `Class` objects are separate, and you wouldn't be able to cast an instance of one class to the other. It's as if they were entirely separate.

Comment: @Rox: That depends on the context, which you haven't told us anything about. We don't even know for sure whether these are running in the same JVM!

Comment: @JonSkeet it's strange indeed. I think `classLoadedByA.equals(classLoadedByB)` should be true, and `classLoadedByA.cast(foreignInstance)` also should run fine, otherwise how can one handle this case? (but maybe this deserves another question and is inappropriate in a comment)

Comment: @Raffaele: You *don't* "handle" this case - you make sure you use a single classloader if you want the types to be the same.

Comment: @Rox: You still haven't explained *how* you've got two applications in  the same JVM. Is this your own application framework, or are these web apps (in which case, which container are you using) or something else?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Maybe I missunderstand your question but I only have one JVM installed, so I expect that it is the only JVM that runs all my applications. It is a web-service I am working on, but I am experimenting on this problem just by using two simple java projects  that I created by NetBeans.

Comment: Both java applications are run like "java -jar app1" and "java -jar app2" so there are two processes when they are running. In both applications I print the system class loader hashcode `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().haschCode()` and it is equal for both applications, but the class that both applications instantiate from the JAR file that both include, does not have an equal hashCode and I cannot understand why.

Comment: @Rox: Right, if they're in separate processes then you've got *completely* separate classes and types. You shouldn't expect `hashCode()` to be consistent across that *at all*. In particular, from the docs for Object.hashCode(): "Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application."

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks for you reply. Look at my second edit in my post above. Why does both applications print the same hashcode for their classloader? Doesn´t that mean that the have been loaded by the same classloader?

Comment: @Rox: *Some* hash code computations will be stable across different processes - but you shouldn't *rely* on it. You should never *store* a hash code from `hashCode()`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Now I think I am starting to understand how stuff work. :-)Does every process have its own SystemClassLoader that loads the java class files belonging to the application? And is it the JVM/Bootstrap classloader that loads the SystemClassLoader?

Answer (score 1):

See the Javadoc for [Object.hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)

> The general contract of hashCode is:
>
> 1. Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once **during an
>    execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently
>    return the same integer**, provided no information used in equals
>    comparisons on the object is modified. **This integer need not remain
>    consistent from one execution of an application to another execution
>    of the same application.**
> 2. If two objects are equal according to the
>    equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the
>    two objects must produce the same integer result.
> 3. It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the
>    equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on
>    each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.
>    However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct
>    integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of
>    hash tables.

Also

> This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of
> the object into an integer

So your result seems perfectly legitimate to me. If you need the hash code to be consistent, maybe you are doing it wrong, since the API is not intended to be used this way. Maybe you could tell your objective.

Answer (score 0):

Think of JAR as static *resource* containing a *recipe* for an application which may be run. When the application is actually run, all the *resources* are loaded into computer's memory using rules specific for an operating system. These rules does not enforce classes to be loaded in the same virtual memory address.

Answer (score 0):

enum is just a key word which makes the declared type class(For example enum Day means you will be having a class like Day extends Enum), class is a simple Template to the object which will be constructed in J.V.M which has its own hash code so obviously when you create a new Object you will get new hash code that is the reason why you are getting new hash code
reffer following link for more details....

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

observe  "All enums implicitly extend java.lang.Enum. Since Java does not support multiple inheritance, an enum cannot extend anything else" this point clearly.